# Selects inside case statements in google big query

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have to do a subselect when the string 'DebugData' contains digits. But in google big query, I get the error "Subselect not allowed inside select clause". Any help would be appreciated !!

```
 %%sql --module Test2
 DEFINE QUERY Test2
 SELECT 
 HardwareId, DebugReason, DebugData, 
 CASE 
  WHEN lower(DebugData) LIKE 'ver%' THEN 'Verizon'
  WHEN lower(DebugData) LIKE 'ro%' THEN 'Rogers'
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(DebugData,'\\d+') THEN c.Network
   (SELECT Network from [red-road-574:RawDebug.CarrierDetails] Where Mcc = SUBSTR(DebugData,0,3) and Mnc = SUBSTR(DebugData,4,7))
  ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData,'\\?',' ')
 END
  as ActualDebugData
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([bigdata:RawDebug.T], TIMESTAMP ('2016-05-15'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-15')))
  CROSS JOIN [bigdata:RawDebug.CarrierDetails] c
  WHERE DebugReason = 50013
  LIMIT 200
```

I tried this but this is not working:

```
 SELECT 
   DebugData, 
   CASE 
     WHEN lower(DebugData) LIKE 'jas%' THEN 'Jasper' 
     WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(DebugData,'\\d+') THEN c.Network
     ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData,'\\?',' ')
   END
  as ActualDebugData 
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([bigdata:RawDebug.T],TIMESTAMP ('2016-05-15'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-15')) d)
  CROSS JOIN [bigdata:RawDebug.CarrierDetails] c
  WHERE d.DebugReason = 50013 and c.Mcc =    SUBSTR(DebugData,0,3)
 LIMIT 200
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT 
   DebugData, 
   CASE 
     WHEN lower(DebugData) LIKE 'jas%' THEN 'Jasper' 
     WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(DebugData,'\\d+') THEN c.Network
     ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData,'\\?',' ')
   END
  as ActualDebugData 
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([bigdata:RawDebug.T],TIMESTAMP ('2016-05-15'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-15')) d)
  LEFT JOIN [bigdata:RawDebug.CarrierDetails] c ON c.Mcc =    SUBSTR(DebugData,0,3)
  WHERE d.DebugReason = 50013 
 LIMIT 200
```

Using `LEFT JOIN` allows it to return rows from the first table that don't match the joining condition.

Comment: I have two where statements, one for the main select and another for subselect. Not sure on how to use two where's for two selects.

Comment: Use one `WHERE` statement and combine them with `AND`.

Comment: I have tried the above code (Added the code in my main section) but that is not working ..

Comment: You've changed the original query in a very significant way. The original query didn't have any dependencies between `CarrierDetails` and `DebugData`, it was just returning the value from a single row in CarrierDetails. `CROSS JOIN` is used when there's no relationship between the tables.

Comment: Sorry I understand that, but this is the original problem i am trying to resolve.

Comment: Corrected the answer to use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112078/discussion-between-user3447653-and-barmar).